# What happens when SVN update command is used?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-update

Suppose I have two files in the repository - file1, file2.
What happens to my local copy when SVN update command is used in the situations below-

1. My working copy contains only file1 (means I have deleted file2).
2. My working copy contains file1, file2, and an added file file3.

Comment: Can't you create a small test repository and test this yourself to find out? Or read the tutorial section of the SVN Book, that explains all of this with examples?

Comment: @KenWhite: Can't you simply answer or ignore the question? :|

Comment: You learn a great deal more by trying things. One of the great things you learn is how to solve problems on your own, without having to rely on someone holding your hand constantly and leading you around. It's the same concept of letting your child learn to walk instead of constantly carrying them - at some point they need to learn to not be helpless. And when you post here at SO, you don't get to decide who comments or answers your questions, because this is a public site. If you don't want to hear from us, don't post here in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.: You get file 2 again.

For 2.: Nothing happened. File 3 doesn’t matter for you scenario.

Comment: @user3545797: You are welcome! If the answer was helpful for you it would be glad if you can up vote and/or accept it.

Comment: @user3545797: Thanks for accepting. +1 for fair play :-)